# Pass multiple argument to back-end API reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, react-redux

I try to pass multiple argument from my action method to my API function in the back-end. With my current code, it does create a new record but the passed value are ${name}, ${country},... so my input value in the client doesn't pass correctly to my back-end.

action method (client side):

```
    export const addNewBeer = (name,country,color, alcoholPercent) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/beers/add/${name}/${country}/${color}/${alcoholPercent}' );
}
```

create method in the back-end

```
app.post('/api/beers/add/:name/:country/:color/:alcoholPercent',requireLogin, (req, res) =>{

    // const{name, country, color, alcoholPercent}= req.body;
    const name =req.params.name;
    const country = req.params.country;
    const color = req.params.color;
    // const alcoholPercent =req.params.alcoholPercent;

    const beer = new Beer({

        name,
        country,
        color,
        // alcoholPercent



    });
```

Comment: I don't understand your question yet

Comment: Probably the "my input value in the client doesn't pass correctly to my back-end" means the author wants help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the ES6 templating feature, you need to use back ticks and not single quotes:

```
`/api/beers/add/${name}/${country}/${color}/${alcoholPercent}`
```